# cannot deply angular app to openshift: "Argument error, options.body."

Tags: node.js, angular, kubernetes, deployment, openshift

I'm trying to deploy angular8 app to Openshift.
I followed some tutorials and I'm trying to do so from command line.
I created the package.json file and then I ran this command:

```
>npx nodeshift --strictSSL=false --dockerImage=bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app --imageTag=10.x --build.env OUTPUT_DIR=dist/readXchange-frontend --expose
```

I have an error I could not find anything on the internet, here the log:

```
2020-04-09T14:16:22.769Z INFO loading configuration
2020-04-09T14:16:22.814Z INFO using namespace readshare at https://api.us-east-2.starter.openshift-online.com:6443
2020-04-09T14:16:22.830Z WARNING a file property was not found in your package.json, archiving the current directory.
2020-04-09T14:16:22.830Z INFO creating archive of .editorconfig, .gitignore, angular.json, browserslist, dist, e2e, karma.conf.js, npx, package-lock.json, package.json, README.md, src, tsconfig.app.json, tsconfig.json, tsconfig.spec.json, tslint.json
2020-04-09T14:16:24.050Z INFO using existing build configuration read-xchange-frontend-s2i
2020-04-09T14:16:24.505Z INFO using existing image stream read-xchange-frontend
2020-04-09T14:16:24.511Z INFO uploading binary archive C:\Users\USER\CODE\angular\readXchange-frontend/tmp/nodeshift/build/archive.tar
2020-04-09T14:16:24.522Z ERROR Argument error, options.body
```

Do you guys know what's happening? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app" is deprecated, you should try this https://github.com/nodeshift/ubi8-s2i-web-app.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `nodeshift` version. It happened to me recently as I was using 3.1. Upgrading to latest (6.0.2) solved the problem.

Comment: A dependecy of a dependecy was updated, and becuase of how nodeshift specified version ranges, it was brought in.  We've now pinned those dependecies, so things are working again.  Here is a link to the github issue for looking into the broken dep: https://github.com/nodeshift/openshift-rest-client/issues/209